# How to prevent a specific users's profile photo (gravatar) from showing on the frontend to other users?

Tags: users, gravatar

Yes, I need a code to do that. Plugin is not an option, I need to use theme's functions.php file.

Maybe this filter would help:

`apply_filters( 'get_avatar', string $avatar, mixed $id_or_email, int $size, string $default, string $alt, array $args )`

I have the user ID.

Comment: If you add code to the theme's function.php, the next theme update will overwrite your changes and your added code will be gone. Best to use a simple plugin (a simple plugin header and your code) to add the functionality you need.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you need to do this?

Comment: @TomJNowell, I user asked and I couldn't do it just for her, so I had to disable gravatar for all users (bad).

Comment: @RickHellewell, I am using a child theme.

Comment: Then adding to the child theme's function.php file will be enough. But you didn't mention that. (Providing more details is always good when asking questions here.)

Comment: @RickHellewell, I said that I would be using theme's functions.php file. I did not ask if that would be ok. The question was related to other thing. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this hook function to replace user's avatar (which is passed in as HTML `<img ...>` tag) if user's ID or email matches your condition. You can use any other default image, or get individual replacement image for each user.

```
function my_get_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    if ($id_or_email == "bad@user.avatar") {
        $img = "http://path.to/default/avatar.jpg";
        $avatar = "<img src='".$img ."' alt='".$alt."' height='".$size."' width='".$size."' />";
    }
    return $avatar;
}
add_filter('get_avatar', 'my_get_avatar', 10, 5);
```

Comment: Can you edit this to explain what it does/how it does it so it isn't just copy pasta?